# The increment in my Java array

Tags: java, loops

Can someone explain what does `++freq` in my given program below?

```
package array;

import java.util.Random;

public class CounterArray {
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Random Ran = new Random();
         int freq[] = new int [7];

         for(int roll=1;roll<100;roll++){
             ++freq[1+Ran.nextInt(6)];
         }
          System.out.println("face\tFrequency");
         for(int face=1;face<freq.length;face++){
             System.out.println(face+"\t"+freq[face]);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the program does is “rolling a dice” 99 times (which smells like an “off by one” error) and count how often each number was found.  The array `freq` holds at position `i` how often `i` was diced.

The code in question generates the next random number and then increments the respective slot in the array.

```
++freq[1 + Ran.nextInt(6)];
```

It will become more clear if we break it apart.

- First, `Ran.nextInt(6)` is evaluated which yields a random integer from the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.  To this, 1 is added to get a number from the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}.  Let's store this intermediate result away in a separate variable for clearness:  `int result = Ran.nextInt(6) + 1`.
- Next, the respective frequency is looked up in the array and incremented by one.  `++freq[result]` which has the same effect as `freq[result] += 1`.

The length of the array `freq` was made to be 7 so the “natural” index can be used.  That is, the element `freq[0]` is wasted.  (I doubt that this is very good style.)

Another word on style: It is generally accepted practice to reserve capital names for types and not use them for variables, so `Ran` should really be named `ran` to avoid confusion.

One further addition: The difference between the **post-increment operator** as in `i++` and the **pre-increment operator**  as in `++i` is that the result of the former expression is the value of `i` *before* the increment while that of the latter is the value *after* the increment.  In your case, it makes no difference because you are not using the result anyway.  To see how this is working, try running the following code:

```
int i = 10;
System.out.printf("i   = %d%n", i);
System.out.printf("i++ = %d%n", i++);
System.out.printf("i   = %d%n", i);
System.out.printf("++i = %d%n", ++i);
System.out.printf("i   = %d%n", i);
```

Comment: Great, just what if `freq[1 + Ran.nextInt(6)]++` be used instead of `++freq[1 + Ran.nextInt(6)]` does it effects on the mechanism of getting random number between 1..6 or no they are the same?

Comment: great, I just wanted to be sure that way has not any effect on getting random mechanism by ran.nextint() which is inside the brackets. +1

Answer (score 2):

It increments by one a random element from the array `freq`.

```
 ++freq[1+Ran.nextInt(6)];
```

The `Ran.nextInt(6)` part gets a random integer between 0 and 5. The 1+ part adds one to the random number. So if the random number is say, 3, you effectively have `++freq[4]` (after addition). Since `freq[4]` is just an integer reference, you can increment it. By using the prefix `++`, you are saying "add one to whatever number comes after me, and set/return it".

So what you are doing is finding a random element in the array and incrementing it by 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is the increment operator and the behavior will be like the following:

```
int temp = 1+Ran.nextInt(6);
freq[temp] = freq[temp] + 1;
```

The part `Ran.nextInt(6)` will generate a number between 0 and 5. So `1+Ran.nextInt(6)` will return a number between 1 and 6. The code will use this number as the index of the array to find which element should be increased by 1.

Comment: This is not correct because `Ran.nextInt(6)` will very likely return different answers each time called.

Comment: still i can't got it :(

Comment: It's still wrong. It should be `freq[temp] = freq[temp] + 1;` following your definition of `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

It simply increments by one the value at the position of the array obtained by `1+Ran.nextInt(6)`. In a more "descriptive" way, you can interpret it as simulating that the dice face you obtained was `1+Ran.nextInt(6)`, and so, the frequency of that face augments by one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know something about some elements used:

- The `++` operator increments the preceding or following variable.
- The method `Random.nextInt(int)` returns an integer.
- You have multiple operations on this line: `++freq[1+Ran.nextInt(6)]`.

What happens is this:

1. `Random.nextInt(6)` returns any integer between 0 and 5, say 4.
2. With this snippet: `1 + Ran.nextInt(6)`, you increment 4 with 1, which results in 5.
3. So you're calling index 5 of the `freq` integer array.
4. Since you have only initialized the size of the array, and not set any values, all values default to `0`<sup>a</sup>.
5. `freq[5]` returns 0, because the value of position 5 of the `freq` array is `0`<sup>a</sup>.

If we rewrite the snippet `++freq[1+Ran.nextInt(6)]`, it will look like this:

```
int diceResult = Ran.nextInt(6); // Returns, say, 4
int index = 1 + diceResult; // We increment dice result by 1
freq[5] = freq[5] + 1;
```

---

<sup>a</sup> Of course, when the loop is repeated, these values might be greater than 0.